# cytoscape.js layouts compound nodes

Tags: javascript, json, cytoscape.js

I would like to create an network representation with cytoscape.

it need to arrange equipment in "site" node  and sites needs to belong/dispatched to regions node (they are 7 régions, maybe 400-500 sites and 700-800 equipments)

so one region has multiple site and one site can have multiple nodes (equipment)

I have some issue to apply layout for more than 1000 nodes.

how to apply layout for each level of nodes and make them together without overlapping ?

can I apply apply layout with selectors ?

thanks for your help !

forgive my approximate English I'm French.

best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vouz pouvez utiliser `data.parent` dans le JSON du noeud.  Il indique le noeud qui est au-dessus de l'autre noeud dans l'hiéarchie.  On généralement utilise [`cose-bilkent`](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cose-bilkent) pour organiser les graphes hiéarchique.  Il y a les autres algorithms hiéarchiques, mais `cose-bilkent` est normalement le meilleur.

--

You can use `data.parent` in the node's JSON.  It indicates the node above it in the compound graph hierarchy.  The [`cose-bilkent`](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cose-bilkent) layout is usually used for compound graphs.  There are other compound layouts, but `cose-bilkent` is often best suited.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer and for your French message :)

Indeed I discover cose-bilkent layout and seems to be efficient for nested node. But I must delete one level of hierarchy (because after 4 hours of treatment the API don't finish the processing) and results are encouraging.

So for parents>sub parents>node maybe I should try to separate my process.

I have 7 parents, so one by one. Save the map in a JSON file, at the end merge all of the 7 json file and use preset layout.

Best regards